# "Finding" the "parent" object in a nested resource relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Say that I have two resources, Project and Task. A Project can have many Tasks; A Task belongs to one Project. Also say that I have Task nested under Project in routes.rb:

```
map.resources :projects do |project|
  project.resources :tasks
end
```

Can one programmatically discover this relationship? Basically, I need to dynamically load an arbitrary object, then figure out if it has a "parent", and then load that parent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing will not help you as this is only meant to be used the other way around.
What you can do is aliasing the relationship with :parent:

```
class Task
  belongs_to :project
  alias :project :parent
end
```

And then use this relationship to detect if a parent object is available:

```
if object.respond_to?(:parent)
  # do something
end
```

Moreover, you can use polymorphic routes if the routes are set up correctly:

```
polymorphic_url([object.parent, object])
```

Comment: This occurred to me just as I was falling asleep last night. Probably the only route to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code above determines the relationship for the routes and helps generate the right helpers to create paths and such.

What you need to make sure is that the relationships are properly declared in your madels. In the project model you should have:

```
has_many :tasks
```

In your task model you should have:

```
belongs_to :project
```

Once you have set that up, you are ready to get what you want.

```
@task = Task.first

unless @task.project.blank?
  project_name = @task.project.name
end
```